# Azure functions with multiple end points (Java)

Tags: java, azure, binding, azure-functions

I can see here a java example for Azure Functions:

```
/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public HttpResponseMessage<String> httpHandler(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponse(400, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        } else {
            return request.createResponse(200, "Hello, " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

The example exposes only one end point,
I understand that it's possible to use Azure Functions to create multiple end points, for example : /name (that executes a certain method) and a different endpoint /id which executes a different method.

how can I achieve this?

What is best practice, I understand I should be using the Azure Function's  `bind` annotations, how is it used?

Comment: Do you mean `create multiple end points` for one http trigger function?

Comment: Single Azure function but with multiple http triggers, for example: host.com/name host.com/id etc.

Comment: One Function app consists of many functions, but one function equals one trigger. The single http trigger needs to be triggered by different routes, is it your scenario? If so,  do the routes have fixed values(e.g. only two values home and id) or the code needs to get the dynamic route value and react according to it?

Comment: Thanks, I want to use fixed routes

Comment: It's beyond what http tigger binding can do. Could [Function proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) be an option for you? i.e. we can set many proxy endpoints, they all point to the same http trigger.

Comment: but I want each end point to trigger a different response for example /name returns a response and /id returns a different response

Comment: I probably overthought your issue, see whether my solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `route` property of `HttpTrigger` and bind its value to a `route` parameter in method signature. Then we can determine the response according to the incoming route.

```
@FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, route="{customRoute}", authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        @BindingName("customRoute")String route,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    if(route.equals("home")){
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Home route request").build();
    }
    else if(route.equals("id")){
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Id route request").build();
    }
    else{
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Not a valid route").build();
    }
}
```

Besides, the Function url is in this format by default `host/api/{customRoute}`. To remove the `api` prefix, set `routePrefix` to empty in `host.json`.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http":{
      "routePrefix":""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks @JerryLiu , in this case what would the URL be, I've tried host.com:7071/api/home and host.com:7071/home and host.comhost.com:7071/api/HttpTrigger-Java/home , but I only receive a 404 for all of them (also when using the "id" route)

Comment: @Tlink If you have published code to Azure, remove port `7071`. Also, if you have set routePrefix to empty, remove `api` as well.

Comment: It's still local, hence the 7071 , http://localhost:7071/id responds with 404 as well as http://localhost:7071/HttpTrigger-Java/id, BUT http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger-Java is 200 , the same way it has been before route changes

Comment: @Tlink Looks like it's still the old function, could you verify that code has been compiled again?

Comment: I have mvn clean and mvn package; now I get this error regarding the host config file :       fail: Host.General[0]
      A host error has occurred
System.FormatException: Unable to parse host configuration file '/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/repos/AzureFunction/target/azure-functions/azurefunction/host.json'. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 2, position 9.

Comment: at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Configuration.HostJsonFileConfigurationSource.HostJsonFileConfigurationProvider.LoadHostConfig(String configFilePath) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Config\HostJsonFileConfigurationSource.cs:line 174
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: @Tlink Seems a little strange, I directly copied the working code here. Do you have any other content in `host.json`?

Comment: @Tlink Did you create the function project using `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype`? If not, try this command to create new project, ensuring we work with latest template and process.

Comment: Thanks @JerryLiu the code I was using was an old archetype, I obtained a new archetype, had to make clean package and rebuild few times after making the above changes, finally it worked, thanks for sticking around through this.

Comment: One more thing I had to change is this part of the test:          '// Invoke
        final HttpResponseMessage ret = new Function().run(req, context);

        // Verify
        assertEquals(ret.getStatus(), HttpStatus.OK);'    because otherwise I get an error

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project azurefunctionjava: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /azurefunctionjava/src/test/java/azurefunctionjava/FunctionTest.java:[53,55] method run in class azurefunctionjava.Function cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: [ERROR]   required: com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>>,java.lang.String,com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext
[ERROR]   found: com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>>,com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR]